# Filter an array, but remove the filtered elements

Tags: performance, php, array

I needed a PHP function that would filter values from one array into a new one, while also removing those values from the original array. After looking through the docs, I didn't see any such function, so I wrote my own. While I don't expect it to run with any comparable efficiency as a native function, I am curious if there are any optimization steps I could be missing.

This code is written for PHP 8.1.X

```php
/**
 * Extract values from an array, and return the results
 * 
 * @param array             $array      The array to filter
 * @param callable|string   $callback   Function to filter the array with
 * 
 * @return array A new array containing the filtered elements
 */
function array_excise(array &$array, callable|string $callback): array {
    $results = [];
    $arr_len = count($array);
    for($i = 0; $i < $arr_len; $i++) {
        if(is_callable($callback))
        {
            if($callback($array[$i]))
            {
                $results[] = $array[$i];
                unset($array[$i]);
            }
        }
        else if(is_string($callback))
        {
            if(call_user_func($callback, $array[$i]))
            {
                $results[] = $array[$i];
                unset($array[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    $array = array_values($array);

    return $results;
}
```

Usage Example:

```php
$people = [
    [
        "name" => "Billy Jean",
        "filter" => false,
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Ronald Reagan",
        "filter" => true,
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Bill Clinton",
        "filter" => true,
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Michael Jackson",
        "filter" => false,
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Johnny Cash",
        "filter" => false,
    ],
];

$presidents = array_excise($people, function($p){ return $p["filter"]; });

print_r($people);

print_r($presidents);

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Billy Jean
            [filter] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Michael Jackson
            [filter] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Johnny Cash
            [filter] =>
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ronald Reagan
            [filter] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bill Clinton
            [filter] => 1
        )

)
*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It might be worth mentioning in your docblock declaration that the input array is required to be an indexed array in your code.
- Your code returns an indexed array and unconditionally re-indexes the mutated input array.  There are scenarios where indexed arrays may damage valuable associative keys. I'll recommend using a `foreach()` to iterate the dataset and avoid forcing indexed keys.  If the code that calls this function needs either of the arrays to be indexed, `array_values()` is not an expensive or ugly call.
- You should not write the `is_callable()` check inside the loop -- it will pass or fail but will not change.  Make the check before looping and return early if the parameter is not callable.
- Both styles of calling the dynamic callback will work regardless of if you declared a string name or an anonymous function, to keep your script lean, just either choose `call_user_func()` or the variably named function for easier reading.
- As a matter of PSR-12 compliance, please do not write `else if` in PHP -- it is a single word.

Suggested code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DM36O)) (or [Demo](https://3v4l.org/oRu1r))

```
function array_excise(array &$array, callable|string $callback): array {
    $result = [];

    if (!is_callable($callback)) {
        return $result;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($callback($value)) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

---

Granted your function is called "excise" -- which infers "cutting away" -- I can appreciate that your function mutates the input array.  However, I do like what @lukas.j mentions about not mutating the input and instead returning all arrays.

If you wanted to move toward that approach, you could set up a grouping function that creates first level keys from the passed in callback parameter.  If your callback returns a boolean result, then expect to handle 0 and 1 group keys. Something like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rQZnu))

```
function array_group(array $array, callable|string $callback): array {
    $groups = [];
    if (!is_callable($callback)) {
        return $groups;
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $groups[$callback($value)][$key] = $value;
    }
    return $groups;
}

var_export(
    array_group(
        $people,
        fn($p) => substr($p["name"], 0, 4)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for these optimizations. I do prefer the "excise" methodology, though maybe I'll change the name to something like `array_slice_by_filter`. That may better convey that the input is expected to be modified. Nonetheless the steps you've outlined are just what I was looking for.

Comment: @GeoffreyH. Excise is a good name. Slice sort of implies taking a contiguous stretch, but this is not necessary for this function.

Answer (score 4):

Generally it is not considered too good a practice to have a function which mutates arguments and at the same time returns values. Side note: Your documentation block does not mention the mutation of the parameter $array.

It might make more sense to build two arrays in the function and return them together, and use array destructuring to assign the two arrays to two variables:

```
function array_excise(array $array, callable|string $callback): array {
  if (!is_callable($callback)) {
    return [];
  }
  $valids = [];
  $invalids = [];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($callback($value)) {
      $valids[$key] = $value;
    } else {
      $invalids[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return [ $valids, $invalids ];
}

[ $presidents, $people ] = array_excise($people, fn($p) => $p["filter"]);
```

But what really would be the solution is to use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$presidents = array_filter($people, fn($item) => $item['filter']);
$nonPresidents = array_filter($people, fn($item) => !$item['filter']);
```

Comment: The name I've seen most other languages and libraries use for such a function is `partition`. [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition), [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#partition), [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html), [haskell](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/partition_f.html). In PHP I'd suggest `array_partition`

Comment: @Boude That is a good comment, which would maybe make more sense as comment below the Question itself, since the function name and signature come from there.

Comment: I made it specifically on your answer, because you changed the signature by returning a pair of arrays instead of modifying the argument, which I do agree with is the better choice. That specific signature in other languages is known as `partition`. I haven't come across a function similar to the question's in other languages, mostly because those would prefer (as you did) a `partition` instead

Comment: @Boude: Of course, makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Overall the code is readable. The other answers have offered great analysis of the code. It seems like a combination of `array_filter()` and `array_diff()` in a single function. I agree with mickmackusa's answer that `foreach` could be used instead of `for`. `foreach` could be used to iterate over the values in various formats - e.g.

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
```

Though if only the keys are needed then `array_keys()` can be used:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $i) {
```

As [this SO answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430538/1575353)

> ...I understand wanting to make things more efficient, but I think you're wasting your time for a micro-optimization. Remember, `Premature Optimization Is The Root Of All Evil`...

The [answer by mickmackusa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278171/120114) mentions this:

> As a matter of PSR-12 compliance, please do not write else if in PHP -- it is a single word.

Many PHP programmers follow standards outlined in [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) like [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) in order to write idiomatic code and follow common conventions.

In [PSR-12 section 4.4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#44-methods-and-functions) it states:

> #### [4.4 Methods and Functions](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#44-methods-and-functions)
>
> Visibility MUST be declared on all methods.
>
> Method names MUST NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate
> protected or private visibility. That is, an underscore prefix
> explicitly has no meaning.
>
> Method and function names MUST NOT be declared with space after the
> method name. The opening brace MUST go on its own line, and the
> closing brace MUST go on the next line following the body. There MUST
> NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis, and there MUST NOT be a
> space before the closing parenthesis.

So the declaration for `array_excise` can be updated so the opening brace is on its own line:

```
function array_excise(array &$array, callable|string $callback): array 
{
```

Conversely in [PSR-12 section 5](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures) it states:

> #### [5. Control Structures](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures)
>
> The general style rules for control structures are as follows:
>
> - **There MUST be one space after the control structure keyword**
> - There MUST NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis
> - There MUST NOT be a space before the closing parenthesis
> - **There MUST be one space between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace**
> - The structure body MUST be indented once

So conditionals like this:

> ```
> if(is_callable($callback))
> {
> ```

can have the new line removed to follow the convention.

```
if (is_callable($callback)) {
```